# Using Pandas Agg Functionality to compute Quantiles

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregation, functools

I am trying to clean up and streamline my code and recently came across named aggregation in Pandas([see link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation))

This note is on the page:

> If your aggregation functions requires additional arguments, partially apply them with functools.partial().

Here is the setup code:

```
from functools import partial as fpart
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


 inputData = {'groupByVar1':['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b'],
         'groupByVar2':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4],
         'value':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]}


 df = pd.DataFrame(inputData)

 upperPercentile = 0.98
 lowerPercentile=0.05
```

Here is the method I have been using

```
nsgdf = df.groupby(['groupByVar1','groupByVar2'])[['value']].quantile(upperPercentile).rename({'value':'upperPercentileValue'},axis=1).reset_index(drop=False)
nsgdf['lowerPercentileValue'] = df.groupby(['groupByVar1','groupByVar2'])[['value']].quantile(lowerPercentile).values
```

Here is the method I would like to use:

```
fpartUpper = fpart(np.quantile,q=upperPercentile)
fpartLower = fpart(np.quantile,q=lowerPercentile)
bdf = df.groupby(['groupByVar1','groupByVar2']).agg(
     upperPercentileValue=pd.NamedAgg(column='value',aggfunc=fpartUpper),
     lowerPercentileValue=pd.NamedAgg(column='value',aggfunc=fpartLower)
)
```

The following Error is returned from Pandas:

> pandas.core.base.SpecificationError: Function names must be unique, found multiple named quantile

However if I execute the following I actually get a result:

```
fpartUpper([1,2,3,4,5])
Out[16]: 4.92
```

How can I get this particular method to work with pandas? What am i missing?  Why is Pandas finding multiple definitions for quantile, where as running the bare function causes no issues?